# Rerender output panel when action method using pageReference

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anyone tell me how to rerender a particular pageblock when the action method using pageReference?

My use case is I want to rerender a particular block when I click the command button

VFP:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Download}" value="download" id="chatterDownload" reRender="FeedFilePanel"/><br/>   
<apex:outputPanel id="FeedFilePanel" rendered={!feedFile}>    
    If you want to download the files that are attached to the Feeds then click below button<br/>  
    <center>
        <apex:commandButton id="uploadZipButton" value="Download Files" action="{!uploadZip}" />
    </center>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex class:

```
public PageReference Download(){  
       feedFile=true;

        if(!feedItemList.isEmpty()){
            String fileName = 'Feeds' +  DateTime.Now() + '.pdf';
            Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            PageReference chatterdownload= Page.ChatterDownload;
            chatterdownload.setRedirect(false);
            return chatterdownload; 
        } 
        else{
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No Feeds, Please select an another Date to Download'));
            return null;
        }     
   }
```

Please someone tell me how to use rerender attribute in that command button?

Comment: Try rerendring the whole form <apex:commandButton action="{!Download}" value="download" id="chatterDownload" reRender="YourFormId"/><br/>

Comment: @ShankerPaudel : it doesnt work if i rerender whole form

Comment: Do you have apex:pagemessage inside your page. It might be that you are geting an error. Please validate debug logs

Comment: @ShankerPaudel : Yeah I have already added apex:pagemessages tag

Comment: Please add its id in  rerender arrtibute yourpagemessageid , yourFormId if pagemessage is not inside your form.

Comment: Command button doesn't use if I am using rerender attribute. I think the problem is using page reference in action method. I don't know how to refresh the page if am using page reference. Please tell me some idea to implement.

Comment: Do one thing create a public variable and set it to. Test, then i your Download method set it to TEST2, render that above the command button and see if that gets rerendred.

Comment: Or do a new start create a new vf page and apex class, play around with rerender attribute. I am sure it works with PageReference

Comment: @ShankerPaudel : I'll try and let you know soon

Comment: @ShankerPaudel : Rerender is not working with pageReference.

Comment: @ShankerPaudel I have tried in new page with rerender attribute and its works fine.But when i use pageReference is not working

Comment: Can you try adding a blank pram <apex:param name="abc" value="123" assignTo="abc"/>

Answer (score 0):

Create an outputPanel which is parent to both commandbutton and your current output pannel and put the parent panel id in reRender in command button.

Your code will look something like this

```
<apex:outputPanel id="parentPanelId">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Download}" value="download" id="chatterDownload" reRender="parentPanelId"/><br/>   
<apex:outputPanel id="FeedFilePanel" rendered={!feedFile}>    
    If you want to download the files that are attached to the Feeds then click below button<br/>  
    <center>
        <apex:commandButton id="uploadZipButton" value="Download Files" action="{!uploadZip}" />
    </center>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: but the first command button is usng pageReference class

Comment: I have tried your idea but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replicate this code and ask if you have any trouble. Please add this code to your org for test. Thanks

Class

```
public class SanxboxPageReferenceCtrl {

    public PageReference testIt() {
        abc = '1234Updated';
        return null;
    }


    public string abc {get; set;}

    public SanxboxPageReferenceCtrl(){
        abc = '1234';
    }
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="SanxboxPageReferenceCtrl">

    <apex:form id="frmMain">
        {!abc} <br></br>
        <apex:commandButton value="Test" reRender="frmMain" action="{!testIt}"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It works fine but If you use page Reference then it will not work.
like add the below snippet to your testIT method.
PageReference newRedirect=new PageRefernce('/apex/YourPreviousPage');
newRedirect.setRedirect(false); return newRedirect;

Comment: If you use rerender you are making an ajax call you cannot redirect like this. You need to use on complete attribute and redirect  on it with javascript.window.location.replace("/apex/abcpage);

Comment: But I need to do some operations after that I wanna to download second pages as html.

Comment: For that do not rerender the page. Do opreations redirect to other page.

Comment: Am using same controller for both first and second page.

Comment: So what redirect to other page.

Comment: My usecase is : I've two vfp.

Comment: My usecase is : I've two vfp.
There is a button in first page. if I click that button then it will download second page as pdf.   
once it is downloaded then it will rerender whole form.for that what I need to

Comment: No Idea looks like a crepy requirement. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is because  of you are using  page-reference and it start apex reading  code from beginning and feedfile got back null try

```
render="{! If(feedFile=='true' ,true,false) }"/>
```

and instead of `return pg` use

```
return null
```

and command button to rerender  form